# Artifactory Pipeline Step & Shared Libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to push a bunch of repeated Jenkinsfile pipeline steps into a shared library.

However i ran into an issue when moving an Artifactory build step; i get this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>   at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.deployers.MavenDeployer["releaseRepo"])
>     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)

I've created an [example Jenkins project](https://github.com/bstopp/example-jenkinsfile) and [a shared library](https://github.com/bstopp/example-library) showing the error.

I get the impression this means you can't run Artifactory setup/build within a shared library. However, i found [a post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/27/standardizing-builds-with-shared-libraries/) that shows *some* things are obviously possible.

I can't find any examples where the deployer/run are actually in a shared library, however.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

-B

Comment: Update to this: It appears this method:

rtMaven.deployer(...)

Does not support passing using parameters in the repository references. This seems very short-sighted as it requires all builds to hard-code their target repositories, and prevents reuse.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue i encountered was one of GString interpolation. The invocation of the *deployer(...)* method required that the parameters be immutable at the time of execution.

To do this, my interpolated strings needed to be converted to immutable strings; resulting in this:

> rtMaven.deployer(releaseRepo: "${config.releaseRepo}", snapshotRepo: "${config.snapshotRepo}", server: artServer)

Becoming this:

> rtMaven.deployer(releaseRepo: config.releaseRepo.toString(), snapshotRepo: config.snapshotRepo.toString(), server: artServer)

-B